# DocuSign.eSign.dll with .net version 4.0 for Windows Application

Tags: .net, nuget, docusignapi, nuget-package, restsharp

Can i get [DocuSign.eSign.dll](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DocuSign.eSign.dll) with .net version 4.0 needed for Windows Application.There is only 4.5 versions available in nuGet. Also need 
[RestSharp](https://www.nuget.org/packages/RestSharpSigned/) with 4.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per documentation [DocuSign C# SDK](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-csharp-client/#requirements) supports .Net framework 4.5 or later.

[DocuSign.eSign.dll](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DocuSign.eSign.dll) is built out of the DocuSign C# sdk.

.Net 4.0 will not be supported.

Comment: So how can i do DocuSign for 4.0 supporting windows application?

Comment: You will have to make direct HTTP calls to docusign API rather than relying on the SDK. https://docs.docusign.com/esign/

Comment: Ok thanks.. Is there is any sample application which is calling docusign from Windows forms.?

Comment: Not that I am aware of. Please post a separate question requesting for a sample. Someone else might provide you one